# If $M$ is a transitive set and $R$ well orders $A$ in $M$, then $R$ well orders $A$ universally

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory

I am asked to prove the following:
Working in ZF - P.

If $M$ is (Edit) a transitive model of ZF - P, and $R, A \in M$, then

$(R \ well \ orders \ A) ^M \rightarrow (R \ well \ orders \ A)$

I am struggling with the minimal element. 
Since $R$ well orders $$A relative to $M$ we have that: $\forall X \in M s.t. X \subset A (X \neq 0 \rightarrow \exists y \in X (\lnot \exists z \in X (zRy))]$

So I need to show that for any $X$ (not necessarily in $M$) s.t. $X \subset A$ and $X \neq 0$,  X has a minimal element.

My idea was to suppose there is such an X with no minimal element and arrive at a contradiction by showing this would imply A has no minimal element but the details of this are tripping me up.

Considering any element $a \in A$ we try to show $\exists b \in A$ s.t. $b R a$.

If $a \in A$ then $a \in X$ or $a \in A-X$. If $a \in X$ then we are done since X has no minimal element so we can always find something smaller.

Now if $ a \in A-X$ then...I want to say something in $X$ is smaller then it? Or possibly compare $a$ and elements in $X$ since those are both in $M$ and hence well ordered there, but I'm getting stuck.

Any assistance would be awesome.

Comment: Do you know any absoluteness theorems?

Comment: Are you given any information about $M$ beyond just that it's a transitive set? For example, is it a model of ZF (or some reasonable fragment of ZF)? Without some such information, I wouldn't expect the claim to be true.

Comment: I have that M is a transitive model of ZF - P. I'll update the original post. I also have some basic absoluteness theorems, (for example the one about $\Delta_0$ formulas).

Comment: Since I guess (not really sure) $ZF^-$ is enough to prove the theorem that states that any wellordered set is iso to a unique ordinal, let $F:\langle A, R\rangle \rightarrow \langle \alpha , \in \rangle$ be an order iso for some ordinal $\alpha$ in $M$. The same $F$ is an order iso in $V$.

Comment: By $ZF^-$ I meant ZF - Powerset.

Comment: Now that we have $ZF^-$ available in $M$, the comment by @ShervinSorouri provides the essential idea of the proof. You still need to check that things like "ordinal" and "order-isomorphism" are absolute, but they are. (They're $\Delta_1$-definable.)